# How to append label inside the cell in excel having multiple data using Java Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing a java program in which I have to take data from Excel file and to put it into another excel file with few more columns.

I am iterating over the row and getting the content.

```
Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
Row outRow = outSheet.createRow(rowIndex);
Cell outCell = outRow.createCell(0);
StringBuffer outputStr = new StringBuffer();

for (int j = 0; j < parseList.size(); j++) {
    StringBuffer buffer = parseList.get(j);

    String[] inventorCellNumbers = buffer.toString().split("/");
    StringBuffer tempBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < inventorCellNumbers.length; i++) {

        Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(Integer
                    .parseInt(inventorCellNumbers[i]));
        Object cellValue = getCellValue(cell, evaluator);

         if ( cellValue != null){
            tempBuffer.append(newLine);
            tempBuffer.append("Name"+cellValue);    
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

expected to have as per the Image 2

[image]

Please help someone.

Comment: Row row = null;

  if (sheet.getRow(rowNo) == null) {
   row = sheet.createRow(rowNo);
  } else {
   row = sheet.getRow(rowNo);
  }

  Cell data = row.getCell(colNo);
  data.setCellStyle(style);

  data.setCellValue(dataToPrint);

Comment: You can append anything on the dataToPrint

Comment: i need to append only label"Name" ,Phone no,Country ....

Comment: Are these labels cell specific ??

Comment: for all the cell there are common....lables ..content will be dynamically added to the cell...Which i am getting ...Iam unable to add Label like Name  to the cell...

Comment: Are you getting any exception ??? or any garbage value ??

Comment: You need to cast this to string [.... Object cellValue  ] as you are trying to append the object to the string